# Detect change in form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a `<form>` and need to detect if anything therein was changed when it is submitted.

My idea was the following: upon loading the form, I'd save its content's `.html()` as a string in the form's `.data()` attribute. Unfortunately, changes do not show up when the form is submitted (please look at the snippets console).

A few things to consider:

- I need to know if the content is actually different, not just whether something was changed but then changed back
- The form has a LOT of different and dynamic elements, so while extracting the information via `.val()`, `.prop('checked')`, etc. is possible, **I'd really rather compare two strings**

```js
$('form').data('data', {oldState: $('form').html()});

$('form').on('submit', e => {
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var oldState = $('form').data('data').oldState;
  var currState = $('form').html();
  
  console.log(oldState);
  console.log(currState);
  console.log(oldState == currState);
  
  if(oldState == currState) {
    $('body').append('<p>same!</p>');
  } else {
    $('body').append('<p>changed!</p>');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" value="Old text">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `serialize()` to check if the input value in form are same or not and then compare two string .Like below :

```js
//getting all data in form 
var data = $('form').serialize();
$('form').on('submit', e => {

  e.preventDefault();
  var currState = $('form').serialize();
  console.log(data == currState);

  if (data == currState) {
    $('body').append('<p>same!</p>');
  } else {
    $('body').append('<p>changed!</p>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="t" value="Old text">
  <input type="checkbox" name="t1" checked>
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you want to check values in submit, if you want to validate something maybe you should look at jquery validation, or you can use [KnockoutJs](https://knockoutjs.com/) to bind inputs and it observe change of it

If you don't want to use any library you should save your data in js object and then in submit save it again and compare two js object not html:

```js
let oldState = getFormData();

$('form').on('submit', e => {  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let currState = getFormData();
  let res = isSame(oldState, currState);
  
  console.log(oldState);
  console.log(currState);
  console.log(res);
  
  if(res)
    $('body').append('<p>same!</p>');
  else
    $('body').append('<p>changed!</p>');
});

function getFormData(){
  return {
    username: $("#username").val(),
    remember: $("#remember").prop('checked')
  };    
}

function isSame(obj1, obj2){
  return JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="username" type="text" value="Old text">
  <input id="remember" type="checkbox" checked>
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

In `getFormData` you can add one class to all same type inputs and check it all in here, for example add .input-box to all textboxes and use something like this:

```
let res = {};
$(".input-box").each(function(i, b){
    res[b.id] = b.value;
});
//Add other fields to res
...
```

In `isSame` if you dont have any dom element or method you can compare objects just with `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Thanks, but this requires me to write custom code for each element and I do not know the contents of the form in advance :)